# Why resources are not loaded with http2

Tags: 22.04, apache2

I have enabled http2 with apache ,

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin contact@***.com
    ServerName dev.***.com
    ServerAlias dev.***.com

    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    H2Push on
    H2PushPriority * after
    H2PushPriority text/css before
    H2PushPriority image/jpg after 32
    H2PushPriority image/jpeg after 32
    H2PushPriority image/png after 32
    H2PushPriority application/javascript interleaved


    ................
```

but I don't undrestand why javascript and css files are loaded with HTTP/1 **not** with HTTP/2

[image]

Some images are loaded with HTTP/2 !!

[image]

Comment: The browser result says that’s the resources we’re coming from the cache rather than the server. You may want to clear the browser cache and reload the page to confirm that http/1.1 is not being used.

Comment: @matigo , oh yes thank you

Comment: look at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf